# recv() read() and send() without waiting

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am learning how to program a Server TCP socket wherein clients can connect to and wait for commands...

```
fd = open("/tmp/myFIFO", O_RDWR);
if(fd<0){
    perror("open() error");
    exit(1);
}

do {
    while ((nbytes = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1)) > 0) {
        buffer[nbytes] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    }
    err = recv(cFD, strbuf, sizeof(strbuf), 0);
    if (err < 0) {
        if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
            perror("  recv() failed");
            state = TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }

    if (err == 0) {
        printf("  Connection closed\n");
        state = TRUE;
        break;
    }

    dSize = err;
    printf("  %d bytes received\n", dSize);
    err = send(cFD, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("  send() failed");
        state = TRUE;
        break;
    }
} while (TRUE);
```

I just get the part of the code where I'm having problem. I'm reading from a pipe. I'm using that to send messages to the client.. but my problem is with recv. it waits for data sent by client before it sends the data read from my pipe to the client. What i want to happen is everytime i send a data to my pipe it goes directly to the client without waiting for recv.. How can this be done?

Here's the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define TRUE             1
#define FALSE            0

typedef struct SERVER_FD{

int sPort;
int serverFD;
int smaxFD; 
int newFD;


}sSD;

int cFD, 
    dSize, 
    err, 
    start = 1,
    state,
    DescRead,
    DCSERVER = FALSE;

struct sockaddr_in  addr, cli_addr;
unsigned long ip;
char strbuf[256];
socklen_t clilen;
fd_set fdin, fduse;

pid_t pid, sid;

int fd=-1;
int nbytes;
char buffer[256];


void process(int ServerFD, int Port, int sMax, int NewSFD);
void cleanUP(int i, int max);
void dlogs(unsigned long ip);
void daemonize();

main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sSD link;
    sSD *sCon;
    sCon = &link;
    sCon->sPort = 53234;

    fd = open("/tmp/myFIFO", O_RDWR);
    if(fd<0){
        perror("open() error");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Starting Server-G\n");

    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL,
    fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);
    sCon->serverFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sCon->serverFD != -1) {
        err = setsockopt(sCon->serverFD, SOL_SOCKET,  SO_REUSEADDR,(char *)&start, sizeof(start));
        if (err != -1) {
            err = ioctl(sCon->serverFD, FIONBIO, (char *)&start);
            if (err != -1){
                process(sCon->serverFD,sCon->sPort,sCon->smaxFD,sCon->newFD);
            }
            else{
                perror("ioctl() failed");
                close(sCon->serverFD);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        else{
            perror("setsockopt() failed");
            close(sCon->serverFD);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    else{
        perror("FAILED CONNECTING TO SOCKET");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   } 
}

void process(int ServerFD, int Port, int sMax, int NewSFD){
    bzero((char *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
    addr.sin_port        = htons(Port);

    err = bind(ServerFD,(struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("bind() failed");
        close(ServerFD);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    daemonize();
    err = listen(ServerFD, 32);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("listen() failed");
        close(ServerFD);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    FD_ZERO(&fdin);
    sMax = ServerFD;
    FD_SET(ServerFD, &fdin);

    do {
        fduse = fdin;
        err = select(sMax + 1, &fduse, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (err < 0) {
            perror("  select() failed");
            break;
        }
        DescRead = err;
        for (cFD=0; cFD <= sMax  &&  DescRead > 0; ++cFD) {
            if (FD_ISSET(cFD, &fduse)) {
                DescRead -= 1;
                if (cFD == ServerFD) {
                    do {
                        NewSFD = accept(ServerFD,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
                        if (NewSFD < 0) {
                            if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
                                perror("  accept() failed");
                                DCSERVER = TRUE;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        ip = ntohl(cli_addr.sin_addr.s_addr);
                        printf("  Connection from %d.%d.%d.%d\n",
                            (int)(ip>>24)&0xff,
                            (int)(ip>>16)&0xff,
                            (int)(ip>>8)&0xff,
                            (int)(ip>>0)&0xff);
                            dlogs(ip);
                        FD_SET(NewSFD, &fdin);
                        if (NewSFD > sMax)
                            sMax = NewSFD;
                    } while (NewSFD != -1);
                }
                else {
                    state = FALSE;
                    do {
                       //PART WHERE I'm Having problems.
                        err = recv(cFD, strbuf, sizeof(strbuf), 0);
                        if (err < 0) {
                            if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
                            perror("  recv() failed");
                            state = TRUE;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        if (err == 0) {
                            printf("  Connection closed\n");
                            state = TRUE;
                            break;
                        }
                        dSize = err;
                        printf("  %d bytes received\n", dSize);
                        while ((nbytes = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1)) > 0) {
                            buffer[nbytes] = '\0';
                            printf("%s\n", buffer);
                        }

                        err = send(cFD, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
                        if (err < 0) {
                            perror("  send() failed");
                            state = TRUE;
                            break;
                        }
                    } while (TRUE);

                    if (state) {
                        close(fd);
                        close(cFD);
                        FD_CLR(cFD, &fdin);
                        if (cFD == sMax) {
                            while (FD_ISSET(sMax, &fdin) == FALSE)
                                sMax -= 1;
                        }
                    }
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } while (DCSERVER == FALSE);
    cleanUP(cFD, sMax);
}

void cleanUP(int i, int max){
    for (i=0; i <= max; ++i) {
        if (FD_ISSET(i, &fdin))
        close(i);
    }
}

void dlogs(unsigned long ip){
    FILE* pFile = fopen("/sockF.txt", "a+");
    fprintf(pFile,"Connection from: %d.%d.%d.%d",
                    (int)(ip>>24)&0xff,
                    (int)(ip>>16)&0xff,
                    (int)(ip>>8)&0xff,
                    (int)(ip>>0)&0xff);
    fclose(pFile);
}

void daemonize(){
    pid = fork();
    if(pid<0){
        perror("fork() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(pid>0){
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    umask(0);

    sid = setsid();
    if(sid<0){
        perror("setsid() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if((chdir("/")) < 0){
        perror("failed changing directory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Sample Output: I am using telnet and putty to test Server

```
From Telnet: IP: 192.168.5.53
Telnet 192.168.5.55 53234

./socks
Starting Server-G
Connection from: 192.168.5.53
```

Now When telnet is connected i use putty to send data to the pipe so the server will read it.

```
From Putty: 
echo "TEST" > /tmp/myFIFO
```

the problem here is that whenever i send the data from putty writing to the pipe the server waits for telnet to send data before it outputs and send the data i've written to the pipe. How can i make both recv and read work at the same tym so when i write to my pipe it will output without waiting for recv?

Thanks

**EDIT:** I've also used thread to read the pipe but it still waits recv() before the server output what have been read to the pipe.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) or [`poll`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) to wait for events on both of your file handles, eg. (using `poll`)

```
#include <poll.h>

//...

struct pollfd pfds[2];
int rc;

/* Wait for input on either one of the fds */
pfds[0].fd = fd;
pfds[0].events = POLLIN;
pfds[1].fd = cFD;
pfds[1].events = POLLIN;

do {
    /* Wait forever for something to happen */
    rc = poll(&pfds, 2, -1);
    /* Error handling elided */
    if (pfds[0].revents & POLLIN)
    {
        /* Read from fd, change pfds[1].events to (POLLIN | POLLOUT) so you know when you
           can write without blocking. also clear pfds[0].events so we don't read until we
           write */
        pfds[0].events = 0;
        pfds[1].events = POLLIN | POLLOUT;
    }

    if (pfds[1].revents & POLLIN)
    {
        /* Read from socket */
    }

    if (pfds[1].revents & POLLOUT)
    {
        /* write to socket, reset events flags */
        pfds[0].events = POLLIN;
        pfds[1].events = POLLIN;
    }
} while (1)
```

Comment: Actually, `select` is nearly becoming obsolete (it can only handle file descriptors less than 256 or 1024), `poll` is the right syscall to use

Comment: Thank you great answer... Will i remove the select part on my code?.. or just add this code in my do loop?.. can i combine both select and poll?